# Use SYS_REFCURSOR function in Select Query Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a function with SYS_REFCURSOR as return type. As of now I using XMLTABLE function, converting into XMLTYPE and then passing columns and extracting values.

But it is causing delays.Is there any other option in Oracle 19c to open any generic refcursor function in Select statement.No pipelined table functions

Comment: It would help to show us a minimal reproducible example of what you are doing and what performance issue(s) you are having.  I have a guess about what you are doing and taking relational data into XML and back out isn't the most efficient thing in the world.  But I'd suspect that performance issues were more likely to be related to the plan used by the ref cursor not pushing the data into XML.